# Weekly rep greater than monthly rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, notification-bar

Today is the 8th of January and my *Month* reputation is smaller than my *Week* reputation. That can't be right, right?

[image: Notification bar reputation]

Comment: The odor is strong in this one, you've apparently also earned more rep today than the whole month.

Comment: @Yannis: Oh - didn't notice that actually :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You lost 85 points on January 1st:

[image]

Calculating the rest of the month's scores: -85 + 7 + 55 + 10 + 35 = 22 (with 55 + 10 + 35 = 100 being this week's total).

Looks correct to me!

Comment: Of course. That was not this week but this month.